# jQuery: Change div content based on id

Tags: jquery, ajax

This has been doing my head in for some time now, so any feedback would be appreciated.

What I would like to achieve is:

1. When a button is clicked, it will remove itself (currently working)
2. When that same button is clicked, I also want it to update a div that gets its id-field automatically/dymanically assigned to it. The button clicked and the div I want to have updated are not in the same div. -- this is where I need help
3. The information that is displayed is fetched from the AJAX call (test.php) which is set to echo the result into that particular div

Example of code HTML/PHP code:

```php
echo "<div class='something'><button id='{$orderid}' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs cancel'>Cancel order</button></div>";

<div class="test" id="<?php echo $orderid; ?>">
text to show here is echo'ed from test.php
</div>
```

The jQuery/AJAX call looks like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cancel', function() {

  var id = this.id
  var divid = $('.test').attr('id');

  $(this).remove();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      divid:divid
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('.test').load('testpage.php .test' + divid).html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Don't worry about the .test, its simply the only way I've managed to get somewhere although that affects all div classes, not a particular one that I want.

This is how it looks like to the user (pardon my ASCII drawing skills):

```
                   status
    ----------------------
    ---------   | 
    | button |  | New
    ---------   |
                |
    ---------   |
    | button |  | Some status
    ---------   |
```

When you click on the button, the status field needs to change in order to reflect that row' status in the database. E.g. let's say, button next to new has id 1, when button is clicked, status has to change.

So when user clicks on button, AJAX fires a php file containing an SQL update statement. When this is complete, the button needs to be gone and the status to reflect the update statement.

Comment: `$('.test').load('testpage.php #'+divid)` ?

Comment: Hi @guradio, I have tried that, and if I do this, it will update all the divs, rather than based on the id of the particular div

Comment: ID should be unique on context

Comment: Also, I am getting this jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Comment: Your PHP has incorrectly nested quotes characters.

Comment: @Phil: That was my fault in the example, should have been corrected now. Thanks :)

Comment: Still looks bad. You have a PHP `echo` then right after that, a HTML `<div>`? Shouldn't there be a `?>`. Also, you have multiple elements with the same ID

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using data attributes instead of ID? It might be easier than using IDs and getting conflicts which is what I think is happening. Good luck.

Sorry this is long, but this is how i would do it.

```js
function LoadData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "exe/testProcess.php",
    data: "action=GetAllRecords",
    success: function(data) {

      var container = $("#container");

      // start by clearning the data if anything was there
      container.empty();

      // loop through the records and print out the data and button
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var item;
        var button;

        // --------------------------------------------------
        // set up item
        // --------------------------------------------------
        item = "<div class='itemBox' data-id='" + data[i].id + "'>ITEM: " + data[i].item + "<span style='float: right;'>" + data[i].status + "</span></div>";
        // --------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------
        // set up button
        // check order status and down show button if canceled
        // --------------------------------------------------
        if (data[i].status != "Canceled") {
          button = "<button class='itemButton' data-id='" + data[i].id + "'>Cancel</button>";
        } else {
          button = "";
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------

        // Append the row
        container.append(item + button);
      }
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
}

function UpdateData(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "exe/testProcess.php",
    data: "action=UpdateRecord&id=" + id,
    success: function(data) {
      LoadData();
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
}

// on button click cancel the order and update
$("body").on("click", ".itemButton", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  UpdateData(id);
});

// start the inital data load
LoadData();

//-----------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------
// exe/testProcess.php
//-----------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
require_once '../master/testdbconnect.php'; // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE

// ----------------------------
// GET POST VAIRIALBES
// ----------------------------
if (isset($_POST['id'])){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
 $id = "";
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])){
 $action = $_POST['action'];
} else {
 $action = "";
}

// ------------------------------------
// UPDATE RECORDS
// ------------------------------------
function UpdateRecord($id){
 
 // update your sql status here
}


// ------------------------------------
// SELECT ALL RECORDS
// ------------------------------------
function GetAllRecords(){
 
  // sql to pull all you data
 
}

?>
```

```css
.itemBox {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}

.itemButton {
  width: 25%;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Icewine, thanks for replying, what you have demonstrated is not quite what I am after. I might have been unclear in my question, so I have added some additional information. Hopefully that'll help

Comment: Updated with how i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, all I had to do was to put `window.location.reload();` in my `AJAX call`.

As such:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {
    divid: divid
  },
  success: function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

This will reload the location, which is good enough for me as it makes the updated content show.

Thanks everyone for your comments and to @Icewine for his suggestion.